# Treat NULL as largest possible value

Tags: sql, sql-server, null, aggregate-functions

I want to get the row with maximum Transaction number Grouped on the basis of `Code`.

```
CREATE TABLE SaleOrder
(
    TransactionNo Int,
    SaleOrderDate DATE,
    Code VARCHAR(25),
    Quantity INT,
    TotalAmount Numeric(18,2),
    Remarks VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (NULL, '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18',  6, 2500, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (1,    '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18',  8, 2600, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (2,    '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18', 12, 3400, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (3,    '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18',  9, 2900, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (4,    '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18',  2,  900, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (NULL, '2018-10-01', 'SO-002-OCT-18',  6, 2500, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (NULL, '2018-10-01', 'SO-003-OCT-18',  6, 2500, 'Hello');
INSERT INTO SaleOrder VALUES (0,    '2018-10-01', 'SO-004-OCT-18',  6, 2500, 'Hello');


SELECT * FROM SaleOrder O
WHERE TransactionNo  = (SELECT MAX(ISNULL(TransactionNo, 1)) FROM SaleOrder GROUP BY Code)
```

Here when TransactionNo is NULL it's not returning any record against it while it should return that too.

Comment: `NULL = NULL` will evaluate to `FALSE`. What is your expected result here? Also, that subquery is going to end up returning more than 1 row with a `GROUP BY` and no `WHERE` or `TOP`.

Comment: A NULL is a NULL, that means not a value. It has no order, nor can it be compared to anything. Sounds like the real question is something else? Perhaps you are looking for `FIRST_VALUE` or `LAST_VALUE`?

Comment: @Larnu, NULL = NULL evaluates to _unknown_.

Comment: TransactionNo column should be declared as NOT NULL.

Comment: NULL seems preeeety big already!

Answer (score 3):

There is absolutely no reason to *treat NULL as largest possible value*. You can always use the `ROW_NUMBER` trick:

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Code ORDER BY TransactionNo DESC) AS RN
    FROM SaleOrder
)
SELECT * FROM cte
WHERE RN = 1
```

Result:

```
| TransactionNo | SaleOrderDate | Code          | Quantity | TotalAmount | Remarks | RN |
|---------------|---------------|---------------|----------|-------------|---------|----|
| 4             | 2018-10-01    | SO-001-OCT-18 | 2        | 900.00      | Hello   | 1  |
| NULL          | 2018-10-01    | SO-002-OCT-18 | 6        | 2500.00     | Hello   | 1  |
| NULL          | 2018-10-01    | SO-003-OCT-18 | 6        | 2500.00     | Hello   | 1  |
| 0             | 2018-10-01    | SO-004-OCT-18 | 6        | 2500.00     | Hello   | 1  |
```

Answer (score 0):

When TransactionNo is NULL and query returns more than one row that could not assigned to the filter

The below may help

```
SELECT * FROM SaleOrder O
WHERE TransactionNo  = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(ISNULL(NULL, 1)) FROM SaleOrder GROUP BY Code)
```

Note that this could take any record with TransactionNo having a NULL value.
Segregating the logic for TransactionNo filter would be easier to extend and maintain. Example below:

```
DECLARE @TransactionNo int

SELECT TOP 1 @TransactionNo = MAX(ISNULL(TransactionNo, 1)) FROM SaleOrder GROUP BY Code -- (OR) Logic here

SELECT * FROM SaleOrder O
WHERE TransactionNo  = @TransactionNo
```

Answer (score 0):

when you use = select in your where clause its totally wrong because this is possible you have multiple records,so you have to change your code like this:

```
SELECT MAX(ISNULL(TransactionNo, 1)),code FROM SaleOrder O
 GROUP BY Code
```

but if you want to return only one record you can use it like this:

```
SELECT * FROM SaleOrder O
WHERE TransactionNo  = (SELECT TOP 1 MAX(ISNULL(NULL, 1)) FROM SaleOrder GROUP BY Code)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think this `ISNULL` check should solve your problem and replace `=` with `IN` subquery can return multiple records

```
WHERE ISNULL(TransactionNo, 1) IN
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select TransactionNo,SaleOrderDate,Code,Quantity,TotalAmount,Remarks from (
    select TransactionNo,SaleOrderDate,Code,Quantity,TotalAmount,Remarks, 
           row_number() over (partition by code order by transactionno desc) rn 
    from (
        select TransactionNo,SaleOrderDate,Code,Quantity,TotalAmount,Remarks,
               coalesce(transactionno, count(*) over (partition by code) + 1) transactionno2
        from SaleOrder
    ) a
) a where rn = 1
```

**Explanation:**

With this line `coalesce(transactionno, count(*) over (partition by code) + 1) transactionno2` I assign greatest value per group (partitioned by `code`) where it's null. **But be aware** when you have two `NULL`s, rows will be tied in this case and it would be **non-deterministic**.

Answer (score 0):

Below code will give you much more info than you requested, you can play with it, add some comment if have any questions.

```
CREATE TABLE #SaleOrder
(
    TransactionNo Int,
    #SaleOrderDate DATE,
    Code VARCHAR(25),
    Quantity INT,
    TotalAmount Numeric(18,2),
    Remarks VARCHAR(25)
)

INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (NULL, '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18', 6, '2500', 'Hello');
INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (1, '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18', 8, '2600', 'Hello');
INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (2, '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18', 12, '3400', 'Hello');
INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (3, '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18', 9, '2900', 'Hello');
INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (4, '2018-10-01', 'SO-001-OCT-18', 2, '900', 'Hello');
INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (NULL, '2018-10-01', 'SO-002-OCT-18', 6, '2500', 'Hello');
INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (NULL, '2018-10-01', 'SO-003-OCT-18', 6, '2500', 'Hello');
INSERT INTO #SaleOrder VALUES (0, '2018-10-01', 'SO-004-OCT-18', 6, '2500', 'Hello');

-- final select
SELECT top 1 -- optional, if you want to return 1 record
    Code,
    sum(Quantity) as totalQuantity, 
    sum(TotalAmount) as totallAmount, 
    count(1) as totalOrdersPerCode
FROM #SaleOrder O
group by Code
order by count(1) desc  

-- drop temp table
drop table #SaleOrder
```